# Hildring - Influence of vertical temperature gradient on light beam curvature

Tags: refraction, geometric-optics, meteorology

In special atmospheric condition it is possible to see coastline that normally is behind the horizon. It is apparently lifted to become visible. In Scandinavian the phenomenon is called 'hildring', a kind of 'fata morgana' over sea, but not mirrored. I'm interested to know if there is a relation between the curvature of the light beam and the vertical temperature gradient, increasing temperature upwards, the first 10 - 40 m above the sea. In that case it may be possible to calculate how far out the horizon is moved  from the straight line tangent distance, $D = \sqrt{2HR}$, $H$ being height above the sea (10 - 20 m) and $R$ the earth radius, 6400 km.

I'd appereciate a reference to an optical description of this phenomenon, as related to the air temperature gradient!